# Raising an exception for failure of loading a fragment

Tags: sapui5

I am using IDP service which automatically logs out the user after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Post this, if a user tries to open a certain dialog, if that fragment.xml itself cannot be fetched, I want to throw an error message. However I don't see and error/exception handlers for the same.

```
            this._upload = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
                "xyz.project.view.Upload",
                this);
            this.getView().addDependent(this._upload);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put this code inside try...catch statement:

```js
try {
  this._upload = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
    "xyz.project.view.Upload", this);
  this.getView().addDependent(this._upload);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e); // eslint-disable-line    
}
```